# Continuity of hypergeometric function $_{1}F_1(a;2;k\pi i)$ in the argument $a$

Tags: limits, continuity, hypergeometric-function

For $0\leq a \leq 2$, are the hypergeometric functions $_{1}F_1(a;2;k\pi i)$, $_{1}F_1(a;2;-k\pi i)$ continuous in the argument $a$? where $k\in \{1,2,3 \}$. How to prove it?

Are the following equations  valid?

$$\lim_{a\to 2} {}_{1}F_1(a;2;\pm k\pi i)={}_{1}F_1(2;2;\pm k\pi i)$$

$$\lim_{a\to 0^+} {}_{1}F_1(a;2;\pm k\pi i)={}_{1}F_1(0;2;\pm k\pi i)$$

$$\lim_{a\to c} {}_{1}F_1(a;2;\pm k\pi i)={}_{1}F_1(c;2;\pm k\pi i)$$

where $0<c<1$.

Comment: I like this question.  Maybe show that for the ${}_1F_1$ series, the terms are continuous in $a$ and the series converges uniformly in $a$?  (I think I recall an example of a hypergeometric where continuity in one of the variables fails, but perhaps that was a case exactly on the radius of convergence.  Here the radius of convergence is infinite.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that ${}_1 F_1(a;2;z)$ is an entire function of both $a$ and $z$. In general, ${}_1 F_1(a;b;z)$ is entire in $a$ and $z$, and is meromorphic in $b$. ${}_1 F_1(a;b;z)/\Gamma(b)$ is entire in all three variables.

Comment: What is entire function? (I found some different definitions of entire function). Why ${}_1 F_1(a;2;z)$ is an entire function? and how this related to the question?

Comment: @Masoud Entire means holomorphic (in particular, continuous) in the whole complex plane.

Comment: Why 1F1(a;2;z) is an entire function?

Comment: Well, the power seires of ${}_1 F_1$ in powers of $z$ converges absolutely and uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $z$. You can also show that it converges, as a function series of holomorphic polynomial functions in $a$, absolutely and uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $a$. These facts imply that it is an entire function in both $z$ and $a$.